# Cannot run individual test case for play framework in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

When I try to run individual test case in a test class using Intellij Idea, It runs all the test cases in the class. I think this is due to superclass UnitTest.

Is there any work around? How do I solve this problem? I guess this problem is unique to Play Framework.

I am using Intellij Idea Community edition 11.0 beta.

Comment: I've seen the same issue using Eclipse

Comment: Then it actually means it is the problem with Play framework.

Answer (score 0):

I run an individual unit test using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>. If this is done with the cursor inside a test case code, only that particular unit test is run. When placed outside, it runs all the unit tests in that class. 
This is the default shortcut & can of course be modified.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use Junit4.11. Intellig has a fix for that version.